# getting error Uncaught ReferenceError: BootstrapDialog is not defined

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm trying to use Bootstrap's modal to send tweets. I downloaded *modal.js* and *bootstrap.min.js* into my JavaScript file, but I'm getting the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: BootstrapDialog is not defined.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

**HTML:**

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/modal.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script> <!-- my jquery file -->
```

**JavaScript:**

```
setTimeout(function() {
    BootstrapDialog.alert('I want banana!');
}, 1000);
```

Comment: did you solve the problem? I got the same error BootstrapDialog is not defined, even though I add bootstrap.min.js before my javascript.

Comment: @abc: I gave up.

Answer (score 6):

You're calling a plugin BootstrapDialog (https://github.com/nakupanda/bootstrap3-dialog) but not including it in your JS files. You're not using only the Bootstrap default modal (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Answer (score 2):

You need to source the `bootstrap-dialog.min.js` file somewhere before your JavaScript runs.

Comment: where do I find this file? I downloaded Bootstrap, and I don't see this file.

Answer (score 2):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.7/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.7/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
setTimeout(function(){
    BootstrapDialog.alert('I want banana!');
}, 1000);
```

also you have to include this script in your main html file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.7/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.7/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css">
```

Also do keep a track on the order in which you are including these scripts.

NOTE:-THIS SOLUTION WORKED FOR ME IT MAY OR MAY NOT WORK FOR YOU.

Answer (score 1):

Just add both to the head section

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.7/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.7/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js
```